# NoClassDefFoundError for class in the classpath but not with ext/lib folder

Tags: java, jar, classpath, jai

I have a Java application which has a dependency on an Epson printer driver which in turn, depends on jai_core.jar and jai_codec.jar. Everything works fine when the JAI jars are in JAVA_HOME/lib/ext but if I put them in a different location and add that location to the application classpath, then I get a NoClassDefFoundError error.

My understanding is that an application shouldn't know or care whether a dependent jar is stored in ext/lib or explicitly listed on the classpath but this appears not to be the case here. Is there some reason why a jar would be found in ext/lib but not in the classpath specified on the command line?

Comment: Does your java process with modified class path launch another java process that may not be inheriting the modified class path? If yes then that would explain it because lib/ext would be added to class path for all processes.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll check this. I'm not doing it myself but it's possible that the driver is.